# CakePHP 2.x - Fetching data from a table without creating a model

Tags: associations, cakephp-2.0

I have just started learning CakePHP and Need help in this situation.

I have one table(Student) and corresponding model (Student) which has one property called 'Educational Qualification' which can have multiple values (MBA, MCA, BCA, BA, PHD) so i have created a master table which contains list of all the degrees.

Now When a Student is going to register himself/herself he has to choose multiple options in qualifications.

I want to get DegreeMst data from database in my View as multiple options.
My question is that in this manytomany relationship Do i have to create a new model DegreeMst and then create ManytoMany relationship with Student model .

Or Can i do this without creating new Model DegreeMst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, if you find yourself needing to fetch data from a table without creating a model in an MVC framework, there's a good chance you're doing something wrong.

If you've really only got 5 possible values (MBA, MCA, BCA, BA, PHD), I'd probably just make them 5 separate tinyint(1) fields in your table, like has_mba, has_mca, etc. Then just show each in your view as a separate checkbox. That's probably the simplest way.

If you don't want to do that, and you definitely want a separate DegreeMst table, then what you'll want is a  [hasAndBelongsToMany relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm).

You'll need a separate join table, something like students_degreemsts, with a student_id and a degreemst_id columns. You don't need to create a Model for the joins table.

Once it's set up, the code in your view to output the checkboxes will be something like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Student.DegreeMst',array('label'=>'Select your degrees','multiple'=>'true'));
```

UPDATE

You'll need 3 database tables, and 2 models. You know about Many-to-Many (ie, what Cake calls hasAndBelongsToMany) relationships and [joins tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)?

In your database, you'll need 3 tables, named according to CakePHP convetions:

students (id, name, address, other_field)
degrees (id, name, another_field)
students_degrees (id, student_id, degree_id)

That last table is your joining table, and it should contain those 2 foreign keys to the students and degrees table. In CakePHP, you don't need a Model or Controller for the joining table.

You obviously do need a model for your Students table, which is where you'll define your hasAndBelongsToMany relationship:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Degree' => array(
        'className' => 'Degree',
        'joinTable' => 'students_degrees',
        'foreignKey' => 'student_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'degree_id',
    ),
);
```

You also need a Model for your degrees table, but you don't neccessarily have to define a hasAndBelongsToMany relationship again in that model, unless you need it.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for taking time to help. As I have the more than 100 values ( 5 was just an example) so I will have to go for your 2nd suggestion. My question now is hasAndBelongsToMany relationship needs to be made with another model (If i am correct) so you are suggesting I need to create 2nd model DegreeMst and then join them with these associations? or I can do with with only one model Student?

Comment: Thanks Joshua for explaining each and every step. this was really helpful i was able to create relationships and corresponding tables. I wish i could vote you up but i do not have the 'reputations' enough to vote you.

Comment: No problems! I think you can still accept the answer as correct, without up-voting. But if not, don't worry - glad to help.

Comment: @joshua.paling up voted for a clear explanation. Deepak, good luck with your project and enjoy CakePHP!